# Translate a Java expression/formula into Objective-C

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

I am a beginner and have a question, I have the following code, wants out of 2 values ​​that are entered in two text fields, the formula is from my Java code, but does not work in Objective-C,

how do I change the following to make it work in Objective-C?

```
double phWert = [self.phWert.text doubleValue];
double khWert = [self.khWert.text doubleValue];

double co2Ergebnis=Math.floor((7.90+Math.log(khWert/(2.8*phWert))/Math.log(10))*100)/100;

self.co2Wert.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", co2Ergebnis];
```

Problem here is apparently Math /math.floor/math.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code by below way:

```
double co2Ergebnis=floor((7.90+log(khWert/(2.8*phWert))/log(10))*100.0)/100.0;
```

Do not forget to include math.h in your header file.

Comment: hi I've previously tried it, but the result is wrong.

Comment: the result of khWert 7 and ph 7 is here 7.450000, the correct result, however, is 19

Comment: Try now by adding precision point to 100. See the updated answer.

Comment: math.h i have include in the header

Comment: du hast recht… ich habe den Fehler wo anders gefunden… Danke Apurv…deine Antwort war richtig…Thanks all

Comment: you're right ... I got the error found somewhere else ... Thanks Apurv ... your answer was correct ... Thanks all